# space between columns titles in tabular

Tags: tables

I am having trouble doing the following in the `tabular` environment:

```
title1   title2
------   ------
a        1
b        2
.        .
.        .
.        .
z        26
```

That, having only the column titles underlined and instead of the usual line across all columns. I want the space in between columns without having a vertical line in between columns.

Comment: Either set two separate `tabular`s, or one with an empty (second) column and use `\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}` (say).

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you give the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package a try. The following MWE (Minimum Working Example) shows how one might use its commands `\toprule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule`. These commands work pretty much like the LaTeX commands `\hline` and `\cline`, except that they provide *much better* spacing above and below the horizontal lines. In addition, the lines created by `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` are heavier (thicker) than those created by `\midrule` and `\cmidrule`, further contributing to a polished appearance of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
title1 & title2 \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-2}
a & 1\\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$\\
z & 26 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]